# Sql error with drupal 7 and wamp

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

Okay, I've been geting this odd error whenever I am trying to do anything from flush caches to edit a block.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La
>   table 'test-site.cache_image' n'existe pas: TRUNCATE {cache_image} ;
>   Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 167 of
>   C:\wamp\www\www.test-site.com\includes\cache.inc).

**line 167 from cache.inc is:**

```
function cache_clear_all($cid = NULL, $bin = NULL, $wildcard = FALSE) {
  if (!isset($cid) && !isset($bin)) {
    // Clear the block cache first, so stale data will
    // not end up in the page cache.
    if (module_exists('block')) {
      cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_block');
    }
    cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_page');
    return;
  }
  return _cache_get_object($bin)->clear($cid, $wildcard); *<- this is line 167*
}
```

Reinstalling drupal is out of the question right now. (the message from wamp is in French for some reason)

Comment: are you sure you have  a table called `test-site.cache_image`?  If youve made a change to the schema, try manually clearing your cache.

Comment: I do just checked from phpmyadmin. How do I manually clear the cache?

Comment: I tried to manually clear my cache through a clear.php file (i found how to do it from the drupal help site but I still get 

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'test-site.cache_image' n'existe pas: TRUNCATE {cache_image} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 167 of C:\wamp\www\www.test-site.com\includes\cache.inc).

Comment: You can manually clear (TRUNCATE) all cache* tables.

Comment: Do you have Drush installed? If so can you try "drush cc all" does that throw you the same error? It sounds like that table doesn't exist, or Drupal may be losing connection to the database by that point

Comment: You can delete cache from phpmyadmin too.. you can empty the tables which name starts with cache_.